# Trying to installing Angular version 15, when latest version installed is 17, throws warning for Unsupported engine

Tags: angular, angular15, angular17, angular-upgrade, angular-devkit

In my System Angular Version 17 was installed. I tried installing Angular 15. To achieve this I tried

1. npm uninstall -g @angular/cli. Angular is successfully uinstalled.
2. npm cache clean(this throws the error, it was suggesting to use --force).Screenshot added.[image]
3. Uninstall node(as I had latest node, i.e, 20).
4. Downloaded node v18.10.0.
5. npm i @angular/cli@15.0.0. This is giving some warning and angular is not installed.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This [table](https://angular.io/guide/versions) shows that the version of ng15.0.x is compatible with the v18.10.0

Make sure that the nodejs is on 18.10.0 version.

run `node -v` to confirm Node 18.10.0 has been installed,

And try to reinstall the project.

To avoid to uninstall and install different version of nodes, you can use [NVM for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) to manage multiple installations of node.js on a Windows computer.